# How to invoke callback functions sequentially

Tags: ros, c++, nodes, spinning, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is how my main looks like:

```
ros::init(argc,argv,"moving");
ros::NodeHandle n1; 
ros::NodeHandle n2;

image_transport::ImageTransport it(n1);
image_transport::ImageTransport it1(n2);

image_transport::Subscriber sub1 = it1.subscribe("camera/rgb/image_color", 1, imageCallback);
image_transport::Subscriber sub2 = it.subscribe("camera/depth/image", 1, depthCallback);

ros::Rate r(10);

while(ros::ok()){
    ros::spinOnce();
    r.sleep();
}
```

I need to first invoke imageCallback and use data it generates in depthCallback function. But ros::spinOnce() calls them in a *random order*.
**How do I call them sequentially, in the order listed, first imageCallback then depthCallback?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200330/how-to-invoke-callback-functions-sequentially/) by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Technically, I don't think the callbacks are actually *random*; rather, they occur in the order in which messages are received...even though that may appear to be random. I mention that because it indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of the mechanism: *you* do not call the callbacks, the callbacks are event-driven, ordered by message reception.

With that said, you want to impose some kind of message reception synchronization. Perhaps something in the [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) package will do? Specifically, it seems to me that [ApproximateTime](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime) would work for you.

If not, off the top of my head, a simple solution would be to use the callbacks to store message values then call a common method. The common method short-circuits unless both message values are filled, otherwise processing the stored values in the order you specify.

It's important to note that the callback mechanism already imposes per-message synchronization (unless you're multi-threading); that is, only one callback executes at any time, and does so to completion. So implementation is straightforward -- you can simply have a boolean flag for each message type, only performing full processing when both are true.

One final (unrelated) point: you do not need two `NodeHandle` objects, as they are reference-counted copies of a global object. See [NodeHandle Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles) or, for more detail, the [NodeHandle API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html) (specifically the [default constructor](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a0eae6a7fd8c216c3f0860aec44ca81ba)).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) on 2015-01-03**:
Thanks for the tip. I used callbacks to store message values and then calling a common method. It worked.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-01-03**:
You're welcome, glad you figured it out. If you think the answer is adequate, please accept it and close the question.